# Count cell values in corresponding cell based on the value of another cell in the same row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program where it counts the number of cells based on a value.

For example, if a cell value in column E = "75", add to the "Air Count", else if column E = "76", add to the "Road Count"

In my data set there is a corresponding cell in column S, with the number of items. I would like to count those items based on their values in Column E. For example, if the cell in column E = "75", then check the corresponding cell in column S, and add it to an "Air Item Count".

I think I'm a bit confused as to where to add this in. I have attempted to add it in, but I haven't got it correct so I just commented it out.

Here is my code:

```
Sub ParseData()

Dim airConCount As Integer, airItemCount As Integer, roadConCount As Integer, roadItemCount As Integer, totalConCount As Integer, _
totalItemCount As Integer

'Find last value in row
Dim LastSVS As Integer
Dim LastRowITEMS As Integer


LastRowSVS = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
'LastRowITEMS = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cel As Range
Dim cel2 As Range
Dim airCounter As Integer
Dim roadCounter As Integer

airCounter = airCounter + 1
roadCounter = roadCounter + 1

'CONSIGNMENT NOTE COUNT
    For Each cel In Range("E2:E" & LastRowSVS)

        If cel.Value = "75" Or cel.Value = "48N" Or cel.Value = "15N" Or cel.Value = "29" Or cel.Value = "701" _
        Or cel.Value = "15D" Or cel.Value = "EP3" Or cel.Value = "X12" Or cel.Value = "753" Or cel.Value = "EP5" _
        Or cel.Value = "X12" Or cel.Value = "753" Or cel.Value = "EP5" Or cel.Value = "1" Or cel.Value = "4" _
        Or cel.Value = "INT" Or cel.Value = "17B" Or cel.Value = "73" Then

        airCounter = airCounter + 1

        Set cel2 = Range("S2:S" & airCounter)


        airConCount = airConCount + 1
        'airItemCount = airItemCount + cel2.Item(19)



        ElseIf cel.Value = "76" Then

        roadConCount = roadConCount + 1
        Set cel2 = Range("J2:J" & roadCounter)
        'roadItemCount = roadItemCount + cel2.Item(19)


        End If

    Next cel
```

Here is a screenshot of my dataset.
[image: dataset]

I would like the Items counted, if they match an attribute in Service.
So, if the Service is 75, count all items in the corresponding row.

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working correctly with your current code? Are you getting an error or an unexpected outcome? If the later, can you describe what you're expect vs the actual outcome. One thing I would note is that you're using `cel2.Item(i, 10)` but I don't see you declare or assign any value to `i` anywhere.

Comment: My apologies. I'm getting error code `Object doesn't support this property or method` The issue I'm having is not knowing where to put the statements to add to the "Air Item Count" and not knowing the correct syntax to use or how to structure it.

Comment: On what line are you getting that error? I just ran that code based on what you've given and it doesn't error. I don't think you're specifying the right cell in the line `airItemCount = airItemCount + cel2.Item(i, 10)` but it's hard to say without a better idea of your data set.

Comment: Are you not getting an error because I've commented out the code that's giving the errors? What more information do you need on my dataset and I will provide it. I am trying to specify column 'S' and count the values in that cell. I thought this would be row '10', and I thought 'i' specifies the value in that For Each loop.

Comment: Sorry, '10', should be '19'. Column 19 I meant.

Comment: Can you use `Select Case` instead of that long IF OR OR OR statement....

Comment: You may be better off adding a screen shot of sample data that reflects your problem and then show us the expected outputs with reasoning to get there. I think there is a much easier way to do this but would need sample data to confirm.

Comment: I have added a screenshot to the original post. Thankyou!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve but if I run that code, and uncomment those two lines, it runs. There are no errors. Also, I recommend you add `MsgBox (airConCount)`, for example, in your code so you can easily see what it's doing in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you need it to do.

It loops through all the cells in the `E2:E` range and depending on if the value is 76 it adds the value of the cell in column S of the same row to `roadItemCount`. If the value is anything else, it does the same logic but adds the value to `airItemCount`.

I've inversed your if/else logic so if you really need to select those specific values in column E you can use your logic.

```vb
Sub ParseData()

Dim airConCount As Integer, airItemCount As Integer, roadConCount As Integer, roadItemCount As Integer, totalConCount As Integer, _
totalItemCount As Integer

'Find last value in row
Dim LastSVS As Integer
Dim LastRowITEMS As Integer


LastRowSVS = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowITEMS = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row

Dim cel As Range
Dim airCounter As Integer
Dim roadCounter As Integer

airCounter = airCounter + 1
roadCounter = roadCounter + 1

'CONSIGNMENT NOTE COUNT
For Each cel In Range("E2:E" & LastRowSVS)

    If cel.Value = "76" Then
        roadConCount = roadConCount + 1
        roadItemCount = roadItemCount + ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row, 19).Value

        'MsgBox ("roadConCount: " & roadConCount)
        'MsgBox ("roadItemCount: " & roadItemCount)
    Else
        airConCount = airConCount + 1
        airItemCount = airItemCount + ActiveSheet.Cells(cel.Row, 19).Value

        'MsgBox ("airConCount: " & airConCount)
        'MsgBox ("airItemCount: " & airItemCount)
    End If

Next cel

MsgBox ("airItemCount: " & airItemCount)
MsgBox ("roadItemCount: " & roadItemCount)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I need. Thank you so much.